# htaccess redirect with variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect from

/med.php?med=№

to

/med?med=№

for the whole site. So far I got here:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} med=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?(med.php)?$  http://example.com/med?med=%1? [L,R=301]
```

This code does not work ("server not found"). Moreover it adds strange symbols like %3f to the end of url.

Now htaccess content looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
#php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
#php_value register_globals 1
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
php_flag register_globals on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^med$ med.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: This code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
#php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
#php_value register_globals 1
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
php_flag register_globals on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /med\.php\?med=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /med [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^med$ med.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Query string is automatically carried forward to the target URL.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. I suspected that you forgot to remove RewriteRule ^med$ med.php [L,NC], removed it myself but with no result as well.

Comment: The url with .php still can be opened while one without .php stopped working.

Comment: Oh I had a minor issue. It is fixed now and you do need both the rules. One for redirecting `med.php` to `/med` in browsers and other is for internal routing.